Is Weasel Poo on a Door Knob a Recognised Expression?
The heading says it all. I have seen the above expression (or a few variants) used to describe something smooth, whether a person, or a literal surface. An example,

When it comes to women, Alex is smooth as weasel poo on a doorknob.

The image it invokes is certainly unusual, and of course not something I would use in a more formal situation. But does it make sense as a casual expression?
If yes, then what's the etymology like, as I cannot imagine how it came to be.
And if not, what other similar expressions can convey the meaning?

Does this answer your question? What does "slicker than snot on a doorknob" mean? Your example is a "one-off" loosely based on that, together with the idea that weasels (and weasel words) are slick / crafty / sly. More coarsely, there's also slick as shit [...on a doorknob, ...on a stick].

I didn't see the duplicate, but my answer below includes earlier, literal versions of "smooth as a doorknob" as well as a discussion of weasels.

There are many similar expressions for something being smooth, either literally or in the sense "excessively and often artfully suave, ingratiating" (Merriam-Webster). If you're faced by an obnoxiously smarmy person, you may look for an inventive and insulting way of describing them. This draws on "smooth as a doorknob" as a metaphor for something literally smooth (often a shaven head, which is doorknob-shaped).
A brass doorknob is very smooth, and anything slippery will make it even smoother. Google finds some recent colorful variants: "smooth as deer guts on a doorknob" (Mystery Magazine), "as smooth as snot on a doorknob" (Snipers Hide), "as smooth as baby poo on a brass doorknob" (Shop Floor Talk). All these are recent posts by random people on forums or minor publications, so it's a productive metaphor where people are trying to be creative.
PR Wilkinson's Thesaurus of Traditional English Metaphors, 2003, has "smooth as a doorknob", so we can take this as something quite traditional. Google Books has a few examples from the 1930s and 1940s e.g. "they shave them smooth as a doorknob down there" from The Screen Player (Screen Actors' Guild journal), Volumes 1–2, 1934. And from 1940 "Next day he came to school with his head shaved smooth as a doorknob", Forty Years a Country Preacher by George B. Gilbert.
Looking at more recent variants in Google Books, there is "smooth as spit on a doorknob" is 2012, Beauty for Ashes by Dorothy Love. Google Books and "smooth as snot on a doorknob" from The Hollow Earth: The Narrative of Mason Algiers Reynolds, Rudy von Bitter Rucker, 1990. Putting something smooth on a doorknob will make it smoother, and in writing terms it's better if it's something interesting, memorable, or grotesque.
I've no idea how weasel poo compares to other mammal poo, but weasels are metaphorically slippery (hence "weaseling out" and the sense "a sneaky, untrustworthy, or insincere person" -- smooth, in other words).
"Smooth as silk" or "smooth as butter" are also common without the doorknob. Silk doesn't seem disparaging: Smooth as Silk is the title of several romantic novels. "Smooth as butter" is in Modern Proverbs and Proverbial Sayings, Bartlett Jere Whiting, 1989, and "smooth as oil" is similar. They may or may not be insults.
